# This view is not constrained vertically. At runtime it will jump to the left unless you add a vertical constraint

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Не могу добавить TabLayout: как только переношу его в дерево компонентов, весь активити полностью пропадает, в дереве компонентов TabLayout не отражается. Если перейти в код, то там он создается. Если удалить этот кусок кода (TabLayout), то изображение активити в design возвращается. Если не удалять, то, помимо вышеописанного, код подчеркнут красным и выдает следующую ошибку: This view is not constrained vertically. At runtime it will jump to the left unless you add a vertical constraint.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перевод ошибки: "Эта вью не ограничена по вертикали, во время работы приложения эта вью будет улетать влево, пока вы не добавите вертикальные ограничения". Вам нужно добавить этой вью атрибуты вида `app:layout_constraint_*` в зависимости от того, как вы хотите расположить эту вью в вашем макете. В вопросе нет самого макета, я предположил, что у вас используется `ConstraintLayout`. Чтобы с большей вероятностью получить ответ — [не прикладывайте код картинкой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120).